Log (un)successful file download in Shiny for R
Let's say we have the following minimal shiny app:
library(shiny)

app <- list(

  ui = fluidPage(

    downloadButton("downloadData", label = "Download")
  ),

  server = function(input, output) {

    output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
      filename = "data.csv",

      content <- function(file) {

        print("Download started") # Function call log

        write.csv(mtcars, file)
      }
    )
  }
)

shiny::runApp(app)

As you can see, I can call print() to "log" to the standard output when the download of "data.csv" has been started.
However, the download can fail for many different reasons: e.g. the user cancels the download, they choose a directory without write permission, or try to save to a drive that has no available space.
Is there a way I could log when the download has finished successfully (or not)? The help page for shiny::downloadHandler() doesn't provide info about this, and I haven't been able to find anything of the sort in StackOverflow or elsewhere.
Thanks!

If you are trying to log an error in the download, your best bet will be to use tryCatch().

Thanks @IfeanyiIdiaye. What I infer from the interface of downloadHandler() is that there is no such a (direct) way to query the exit status of the download. It just creates a temporary (I assume) file with the result of argument content, and then starts the download of that file with the name in filename. But there doesn't seem to be a way to "know" what happened after the download started.

A response was given so far in the Posit community.
